# Cambio de estatus de promoción con eventos mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, mariadb

he estado intentando crear un evento en MySql que se ejecute cada día a partir de la fecha de creación de una promoción determinada por cada producto, cada producto tiene un campo llamado prom_fechaInicio y el campo de fiscalización de la promoción prom_fechaFin , una vez llegada la fecha final de la promoción se debe cambiar el estatus de la promoción a 0 cuando llegue a su fecha de vencimiento, cada producto tiene fechas de vencimiento distintas, pero no he logrado,

este es mi código de evento que tengo y no funciona:

```
    DELIMITER //

CREATE EVENT cambio_status_promocion ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
STARTS promocion.prom_fechaInicio DO
IF promocion.prom_fechaFin <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() THEN
   UPDATE promocion SET promocion.prom_status = 0;
END IF//

DELIMITER ;
```

anexo la estructura de mi tabla[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Precisamente ayer comenté una situación muy similar: ¿Para qué utilizas un `IF` en vez de un `WHERE` en el `UPDATE`? Recuerda: el `UPDATE` necesita tanto el `WHERE` como el `DELETE FROM` https://youtube.com/watch?v=i_cVJgIz_Cs

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT cambio_status_promocion ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
STARTS promocion.prom_fechaInicio DO
   UPDATE promocion SET promocion.prom_status = 0
     WHERE promocion.prom_fechaFin <= NOW();
DELIMITER ;
```

No le encargues a un `IF` el trabajo de un `WHERE` :)

Y de forma análoga para el inicio de la promoción. Si necesitas ayuda, añade el dataset a tu pregunta (phpMyAdmin, Exportar) y déjame un comentario